# Controller override in Magento

Tags: php, magento, overriding, magento-1.7, mage

Hello friend i need to over ride magento core controller

i want to override a `Mage\ImportExport\controllers\Adminhtml\ExportController.php`

In my `community\compnyname\modulename\controllers\Adminhtml`

this is my `config.xml in \compnyname\modulename\etc`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <company_module>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </company_module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <rewrite>
            <company_module>
                <from><![CDATA[#^/controller/adminhtml/#]]></from>
                <to>/controller/adminhtml/</to>
            </company_module>
        </rewrite>
    </global>
</config>
```

this is my controller code in `\compnyname\modulename\controllers\Adminhtml\ExportController.php`

```
<?php
require_once('/Mage/ImportExport/controllers/Adminhtml/ExportController.php');
class company_module_ImportExport_Controller_Adminhtml_ExportController extends Mage_ImportExport_Adminhtml_ExportController
{
    function indexAction()
    {
        echo "i am called";die;
    }
}
?>
```

Please help me in override a controller

Where is problem in my code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A rewrite like that is deprecated since Magento 1.3 (2009). You can read more about it [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_overload_a_controller).

What you would want to do instead is like the following:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <companyname_exportproduct before="Mage_ImportExport_Adminhtml">Companyname_ExportProduct_Adminhtml</companyname_exportproduct>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Your classname and require looks a bit off as well. And it's good practice to not end php class files with a php end tag since it could accidentally include a whitespace that would mess up sent headers order.

So having said that I'd change your class file to:

```
<?php
require_once('Mage/ImportExport/controllers/Adminhtml/ExportController.php');
class Companyname_ExportProduct_Adminhtml_ExportController extends Mage_ImportExport_Adminhtml_ExportController
{
    function indexAction()
    {
        echo "i am called";die;
    }
}
```

And just in case you have forgot I'm including the file you would have to have in app/etc/modules to make your module active:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Companyname_ExportProduct>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </Companyname_ExportProduct>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a little notification on the include path of the controller.

This include path **can cause errors** if the **Magento Compiler mode** is turned on.

```
require_once 'Mage/ImportExport/controllers/Adminhtml/ExportController.php';
```

Instead of that it is **good to use**

```
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_ImportExport').DS.'Adminhtml_ExportController.php';
```

It will be safer.
Hope this helps..